# XSLT xsl:key - exclude input from report

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslkey

`

```
<Fruits>
    <Fruit>
        <Name>Mango</Name>
        <Price>20</Price>
        <Vendor>Vendor1</Vendor>
        <State>AK</State>
        <Status>Delivered</Status>
        <ProductCode>123</ProductCode>
    </Fruit>
    <Fruit>
        <Name>Apple</Name>
        <Price>34</Price>
        <Vendor>Vendor2</Vendor>
        <State>AS</State>
        <Status>Delivered</Status>
        <ProductCode>111</ProductCode>
    </Fruit>
    <Fruit>
        <Name>Mango</Name>
        <Price>20</Price>
        <Vendor>Vendor3</Vendor>
        <State>FL</State>
        <Status>Delivered</Status>
        <ProductCode>123</ProductCode>
    </Fruit>
    <Fruit>
        <Name>Papaya</Name>
        <Price>5</Price>
        <Vendor>Vendor4</Vendor>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Status>Sold</Status>
        <ProductCode>222</ProductCode>
</Fruit>
</Fruits>
```

`

I don't wan to include Mango to report because the status is Delivered to another state with the same ProductCode, Price and Status.

Expected output:

`ProductCode     Fruit               Price
111              Apple               34
222              Papaya              5`

Comment: Please show the XSLT you are using. Thanks.

Comment: "*because the status is Delivered to another state with the same ProductCode, Price and Status.*" That can be read in number of ways. Please provide a more exact statement of the criteria.

Comment: It sounds like you want a way to exclude `Fruit`s that have the same ProductCode, Price, Status, and perhaps Name?  Please clarify.  Also, if you're using XSLT 2.0, you have options other than `xsl:key`s that might make more sense.

Comment: Thank you all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Fruit" 
  group-by="string-join((ProductGroup, Price, Status), '~')">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()=1]"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

The effect of the predicate `[last()=1]` is to process the group only if its size is 1.

Comment: what is the purpose of '~' in string-join?

Comment: Chosen as an arbitrary separator character that's unlikely to appear in your data. If you were grouping on (First Name, Last Name) then it would ensure that JANE~THORNTON is not grouped with JANET~HORNTON.